# Why does selecting "New Scratch File" using the "Find Action" menu, or its designated hot key combo, not do anything?

Tags: pycharm

As you can see in this screen shot, I am able to search for the "create new scratch file" command using Ctrl+Shift+A ("Find Action").

[image]

However, clicking on the suggested command does nothing. Similarly, pressing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Insert does nothing either. Why is that? I have Ubuntu 14.04, and PyCharm Professional 4.0.6.